# Pandas group rows with the same column values and apply function to the first row then assignment result to the left rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a df, the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
    
        df = """
  ValOption  RB test contrat
0       SLA  4  3    23
1       AC   5  4    12
2       SLA  5  5    23
3       AC   2  4    39
4       SLA  5  5    26
5       AC   5  4    52
6       SLA  4  3    64

"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')
```

Out put:

```
      ValOption  RB  test  contrat
0       SLA   4     3       23
1        AC   5     4       12
2       SLA   5     5       23
3        AC   2     4       39
4       SLA   5     5       26
5        AC   5     4       52
6       SLA   4     3       64
```

Now I want to group the rows that have the same 'ValOption' and 'RB' together:

```
df.sort_values(['ValOption', 'RB']).set_index(['ValOption', 'RB'])
```

out put:
[image]

Notice:since there are many many rows and the value of RB is dynamic so I can't use something like:

```
df.loc[df['ValOption']=='AC'&df['RB']==5]
```

Now I want to apply a function to each row:

```
    def func(row):
        v1=row['RB']*3
        v2=row['test']-1
        return v1+v2
    df['new_col']==df.apply(lambda row:func(row), axis=1)
```

Out put:

```
   ValOption    RB  test    contrat new_col
0   SLA          4  3         23    14
1   AC           5  4         12    18
2   SLA          5  5         23    19
3   AC           2  4         39    9
4   SLA          5  5         26    19
5   AC           5  4         52    18
6   SLA          4  3         64    14
```

However, in my real business the size is very large and extreme complicated,that's the reason I only use pd.apply function to apply the function to each row,I know this the very slow method compare to use numpy:

```
def func():
   v1=df['RB'].values*3
   v2=df['test'].values-1
   return v1+v2
df['new_col']=func(df)
```

This code will get the same result and faster ,but my function is too complicated I can only use pands.apply function ,I have tried 2 weeks.

So my question is, after I grouped the rows with same column values, how can I apply function to the group and only apply to the first row, so that I don't need calculate repeatedly, because the variables are the same ,instead I directly assignment the first rows calculation result to other rows that have the same column values.

The final goal is to save time when program running large size files.

The code is something like:

```
new_value_of_first_row=group['SLA'].each_group(group:RB==4 and group:RB==5).first_row.apply(lambda row: func(row),axis=1)


new_value_of_other_rows = new_value_of_first_row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to remove duplicates on a dataframe, perform a computation, and then restore the duplicates to the original shape.

For this, it saves the index of the first row per group, then `drop_duplicates`, and after computation, `reindex`:

```
# save indexer
idx = df.groupby(['ValOption', 'RB', 'test'])['ValOption'].transform(lambda s: s.index[0])

# drop duplicates
df2 = df.drop_duplicates().copy()

# perform computation (to replace with the actual function, eventually with apply)
df2['newcol'] = df2['RB']*3+df2['test']-1

# reindex to original shape
df2.reindex(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hi @mozway,I really appreciate your answer ,and I'm very sorry to disturb you, I updated my question add one more column 'contract',can you help me check with that,because in my real business I have hundreds of columns in the dataframe I can't do simple drop duplicated.I tried your code in that situation ,will has issue.

Comment: @William I am sorry, but I don't really see where you're going. If you have extra columns, split the dataframe to have only the duplicated columns on one side and the others on the other side, apply the solution above and `join` the other columns.

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me with this related one ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to apply a function only on the first item of each group.
You could create a mask (with `groupby`+`cumcount`) and then use `where` (or `mask`) to assign the output of your function on the selected rows:

```
df['RB_new'] = df['RB'].where(df.groupby(['ValOption', 'RB']).cumcount().ne(0),
                              df['RB']*3 # to replace with your (vector) function
                              )
```

output (in a new column for clarity):

```
  ValOption  RB  RB_new
0       SLA   4      12
1        AC   5      15
2       SLA   5      15
3        PG   5      15
4       SLA   5       5
5        PC   4      12
6       SLA   4       4
7        AC   5       5
8        PC   4       4
```

##### Alternative (useful for non-vectorial functions):

```
def func(s):
    s = s.copy()
    s.iloc[0] *= 3
    return s

df['RB_new'] = (df.groupby(['ValOption', 'RB'],
                           as_index=False, sort=False)['RB']
                  .transform(func)
                )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,what does .cumcount() and .ne(0) mean?

Comment: `cumcount` assigns an increasing number to the rows per group, and `ne(0)` is "not equal to 0" or `!= 0`. This is used to select the first row per group.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,what if I have multiple variables ,not only df['RB'],but also df['EB']  and so on ?Thanks again.

Comment: You can apply the process on all columns if the transformation is the same: `new_df = df.where(mask, df*3)`

Comment: @William did it work as you want?

Comment: Please give 30 minutes to combine it to my code,thank you very much,I will let you know :)

Comment: Hi friend,thank you very much,for the non-vectorial functions,how to add more columns as variables in the function ? I tried: (df.groupby(['ValOption', 'RB'],
                           as_index=False, sort=False)['RB','another_column'] ,but failed,because in the real business logic I will need used about 5 different columns values to do calculation

Comment: @William please provide an example

Comment: Sure,1 minutes!

Comment: Hi @mozway friend,I have update my question, please help  check,thank you very much!

Comment: @William what is not clear is the type of function in your real use case, will it be multiplications/additions? In this case you might just want to apply it as a vector rather than going with the complex transformation per group

Comment: Hi friend ,the function will be very complicated ,that's why I can only use pd.apply ,if I use numpy vector to do it,it has error,I have tried 2 weeks.Your answer is very good,can you just let me know ,what if I have 2 variables ,your answer is about one variable 'RB',how to add 'test' in your answer ?

Comment: your method is faster than pd.apply() I tested it,but just have no idea how to add another variable in it

Comment: So, let me rephrase, you have duplicated rows (on all columns), you want to compute something and make all other duplicates have the same value?

Comment: I provided a separate answer for clarity